# URLSession.shared request crashing Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

why Is this thing crashing just can't figure out

```
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)! )
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            guard let responceSafe = response else {
            completion([:], 0)
                return
            }
/*some not related code*/
}
```

here how weird the error log looks like :

```
Assertion failed: (isForProxy(authConfig.getConnectionType())), function updateWithResponse, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-808.0.2/HTTP/HTTPAuthentication/AuthenticationHelpers.cpp, line 1168.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it's InMobi who makes the trouble. InMobi is a 3rd SDK.
And when I remove code about it, the crash disappears!